# "Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)", Chapter Zero, P11

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I request a hint, clarification (if needed), or your approval (if my doutful solution is correct) for this problem:

> **Problem 11.** A teacher drew several circles on a sheet of paper. Then he asked
> a student "How many circles are there?" "Seven," was the answer. "Correct! So,
> how many circles are there?" the teacher asked another student. "Five," answered
> the student. "Absolutely right!" replied the teacher. How many circles were really
> drawn on the sheet?

Every hint or clarification you propose is really acknowledged. [Here's the link of the book](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzaceatrvbbe7uiociukumvsw5qqfuculusi7ava5ktln2ucmmyntqvri?filename=Dmitri%20Fomin%2C%20Sergey%20Genkin%2C%20Ilia%20V.%20Itenberg%20-%20Mathematical%20Circles_%20Russian%20Experience%20%28Mathematical%20World%2C%20Vol.%207%29%20%281996%29.pdf) in case you need it.

---

Here's my doubtful solution:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCNMV.png 
>  My solution contemplated an additional square. So if we count only complete circles, there are 5 circles in total; but, if we count half circles, we obtain 4. If we join them, we obtain 2 new circles. So there are 7 circles in total.

---

Thank you very much!

P.S. You may note that the book has a section of answers and hints. However, I eagerly wish to discuss the problem, and solve it (being given your approval) without seeing the answer. Without seeing the answer and receiveing feedback, I own the possibility of re-thinking my answer, refining it, and improving my mathematical thinking. This is by far the most important exercise for me.

P.S.S. I am not an English-native speaker, so every correction to my writing is really appreciated!

Comment: This question is not really about mathematics, and would be better suited on puzzling.stackexchange.

Comment: It is the third time you post this question in 2 days !

Answer (score 1):

The teacher was not standing at one of the extreme ends of the classroom. That is, the teacher had a few students to his left, and a few to his right.